# For Loop runs one extra time than the length specified

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, phone-call

In Dynamics CRM, I'm using javascript at custom activity entity to create the phone calls. following is the for loop that runs to create the phone calls.

```
for (var indxAttendees = 0; indxAttendees < respondent.length; indxAttendees++) {
        //List of parameters for phone call

    XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Create(createPhCall);
}
```

But it runs one extra times than the length specified and also create an extra phone call
I need your help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code in the console :

```
var respodent = ["a","b","c"]; 
for (var indxAttendees = 0; indxAttendees < respondent.length; indxAttendees++) {
            //List of parameters for phone call

       console.log(indxAttendees);
    }
```

and output is:

```
0
1
2
```

So check **respodent** length properly, I don't think there is any issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should name your respondents a, b, c  to avoid confusion between them and the index which runs from 0 to 2.

Comment: I've checked through debugger. It runs equal to specified length but the extra record created after a short interval.